# Yii2 REST do sorting when response JSON

Tags: json, sorting, yii2, response

When the JSON format is response, the original sorting of the data is lost. When response in XML, the sort is saved. How can I preserve the original sorting with JSON?

My controller:

```
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class  DomainController extends ActiveController
{
    ...
    public function behaviors()
    {
      $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
      $behaviors['corsFilter' ] = [
          'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
      ];

      $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ],
      ];

      return $behaviors;
    }
```

And action in the controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $domains =  Domain::find()
        ->leftJoin('WEB_DOMAIN_PRIORITY', 'WEB_DOMAIN_PRIORITY.id = WEB_DOMAIN.priority_id')
        ->orderBy(['priority' => SORT_DESC])->all();

    $test = [];

    foreach ($domains as $domain) {
        $test[$domain->id] = $domain->title;
    }
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($test);die;  < -- its ok. right sort
    //return $test;                      < -- its wrong. sort is changed
}
```

And if i change in behavior this:

```
'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
```

To:

```
'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_XML,
```

I have xml response with right sort.

Only JSON response sorting my array by array keys(ASC).

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
$test[$domain->id] = $domain->title;
```

you are adding new array keys. This could change order based on rest/Serializer.

You could apply preserveKeys to serializer as here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-serializer.html#$preserveKeys-detail
or don't change keys order.

Answer (score 0):

@Fabrizio Caldarelli not exactly. In this moment response preparing [JsonResponseFormatter](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/JsonResponseFormatter.php#L90) and it use [yii\helpers\Json::encode](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/Json.php) for format data.